# Why html <A> tag layout offset is different that its parent?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, css-float

This issue started with codedui automation, but it seems it is a pure html issue. Codedui was able to find the control but was highlighting it in a wrong place, and ultimately was clicking at wrong place too.

After digging some ground i found that there was a fontawesome icon in that hyperlink with style `float: left`. This was causing the hyperlink`<a>` (not `<i>` inside the hyperlink) to move few pixels on right side.

Now I will come to HTML part. Below is the sample html structure

```html
<body>
  <div style="margin:100px;">
    <a href="#">
      <i style="float: left;">hello</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Layout offset of above html tags are:

```
<Div> X= 108, Y= 100
<A>   X= 140, Y= 86   <---
<I>   X= 108, Y= 100
```

**Question:** If `float: left` is set on any child of hyperlink tag then why does the hyperlink moves away from its current position.

If we remove the `float: left` from  tag then all lines up at 108x100. In actual project `<i>` is used for fontawesome icon with a `float: left` on it. Not sure why dev have used float there. But my question remains. Why should it affect `<a>` position.

Just for info, I checked the layout details in IE9. [image]

Comment: White space maybe or try changing the display type of the `a`.

Comment: Probably just that you also need to contain the float. So add `display:block;overflow:hidden` to the `<a/>`

Comment: `display:block` does solve it. Thanks.